# Change the value of "data-image" attribute

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I would like to display different images dynamically in several div by using switch and jquery.
I have to add the image in `data-image=""`.

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="tb-image-carte" aria-hidden="true">
    <div data-image="" class="--contain"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="tb-image-carte" aria-hidden="true">
    <div data-image="" class="--contain"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="tb-image-carte" aria-hidden="true">
    <div data-image="" class="--contain"></div>
 </div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
var imageCarte = $('data-image');
    res.forEach(function(image) {
      switch (image.imageCode) { 
        case "1":
        case "2": 
        imageCarte = "the beach" 
        break
        case "3":
        case "4": 
        imageCarte = "home" 
        break
      }
    });
```

I would like to add a value to each `data-image` according to the conditions

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the jQuery **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** method instead :

```
var imageCarte = $('div[data-image]');

res.forEach(function(image) {
  switch (image.imageCode) { 
    case "1":
    case "2": 
        imageCarte.data("image", "the beach");
    break
    case "3":
    case "4": 
        imageCarte.data("image", "home");
    break
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it still doesn't work but I keep looking with what you wrote :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
$(".tb-image-carte>div">.attr("data-image","newattrdata");
```

I would recomend to put an ID to the image div to avoid errors or at least be more clear with class selection:

```
<div data-image="" class="--contain" id="image1"></div>

//SO yo can do:
$("#image1").attr("data-image","new Data image");
```

Comment: @Cristian69 Thank you very much, your first solution works very well. But you're right I'll add ID.  You just forgot a little parenthesis in your code :)

Comment: Is to be more sure, because if you have 2 `tb-image-carte` elements the `attr` will be changed in both

Comment: However if I have to put several times the same div it will not display me all the images, knowing that I should not add a different id for each div. I edited my question

Comment: @mathiasF You want to put the same image in all the 3 divs??

Comment: No, I want the image in each div to be displayed dynamically according to the switching conditions. For the moment it displays the last image it finds in the list of objects I get.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the value of data-image line this:

$("div.--contain").attr("data-image","new-value");